# PTVSD Visual Studio version mismatch

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

I' trying to debug a remote python application in a Linux system from Visual Studio 2013 using ptvsd. I followed the tutorial in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-cross-platform-remote)

The problem is that I am getting this error even when both versions, the Linux one and the VS one are the latest one (3.1.0):
[image]

Here is the linux version:

```
[default@localhost ~]$ pip list | grep ptvsd
ptvsd (3.1.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is installing in both systems the version equal or less than the one said in this table:

```
2017                    3.0.0

2015                    2.2.6

2013                    2.2.2

2012, 2010              2.1
```

So for 2013:

```
sudo pip install "ptvsd<=2.2.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it working with "ptvsd==3.0.0"  installed in both local machine and on the remote machine.

Also make sure your web serve does not reload automatically. that will break the connection. (this cost me many hours)